# Extensions in NetLogo 6.0.1

Tags: netlogo

I am having problems with a model in NetLogo 6.0.1 that opens fine, runs a couple of times and then after I edit it and press 'Check' it complains that it can't find the extensions it uses (r, nw, palette and csv) and offers to take me to the download site.  The model consistently runs at least once before this occurs but it occurs after a variable number of coding changes.  This problem effectively means I can't debug it as each time I make a change I have to close/reopen the file. In an effort to solve this I have:

1. Copied the extensions folders to the same directory as the model
   file
2. Tried to use the model on multiple computers and on Linux
   and Windows
3. Extracted the code and completely rebuilt the model
   interface, etc.

None of these have made any difference. Any solutions/ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's very weird! But it sounds like this could be a consequence of something that your model *does* that somehow messes the environment. It's very hard to diagnose without seeing your whole code, though. Maybe try progressively removing parts of your code until the problem stops in order to narrow it down? Start with the parts that use extensions... they're more likely to be the culprit(s)...